# How can I retrieve the location in a drillthrough postprocessor ?

Tags: activepivot

I would like to apply some logic in a drillthrough postprocessor which depends on the location where the drillthrough has been requested.

For instance, let's say I have a risk vector and a list of maturities. If the user executes its drillthrough on the maturity 3M, I would like to display the risk value for that maturity in the drillthrough.

I was thinking about setting a context value with the location, and then retrieve it in the DT post processor, but I would be happy if there is an easier way :)

Regards,

Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. My question was indeed involving analysis dimensions and vectors.

I have solved it by setting a context value in a custom UpdateDrillthroughFeedHandler as defined on confluence (http://support.quartetfs.com/confluence/display/LIVE/Extensions#Extensions-Customizationentrypoints), and retrieving it in a drillthrough post processor.

Regards,

Christophe

Answer (score 2):

In ActivePivot, from a post processed property such as those you can write to customize drillthrough you have indeed access to all the standard attributes of the current drillthrough row.

In the ActivePivot Sandbox application, since version 5.0 there is an example of drillthrough post processed property that extracts the book id that way:

```
/**
 * @author Quartet FS
 */
@QuartetExtendedPluginValue(intf = IPostProcessedProperty.class, key = BookIdColumnPostProcessor.PLUGIN_KEY)
public class BookIdColumnPostProcessor extends APostProcessedProperty {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String PLUGIN_KEY = "BookIdColumn";

    public BookIdColumnPostProcessor(Properties properties) {
        super(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(Object target) {
        // Retrieve the value in the BookId column.
        BookId book = (BookId) attributeAccessors.get("BookId").getValue(target);
        return book.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return PLUGIN_KEY;
    }

}
```

Comment: What if your maturity hierarchy is an analysis hierarchy and your attribute a vector ? For instance if you want to return the whole vector if defaultDiscriminator but only the corresponding element for another location - is there any way to retrieve this information apart from using context values ?

Comment: Reasoning on analysis hierachies is indeed not possible with the post processed property API. This more advanced use case will demand more customization at a higher level (something like a custom drillthrough query).